# How to toggle style in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to toggle `style`in JavaScript. Not familiar with JavaScript but could I somehow toggle this:

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
```

It's part of this function:

```
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('change');
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden' 
}
```

I'd like it to apply when I press it, and not apply when I press it again.   At the moment it applies when i initiate the function, but doesn't stop applying when I retoggle the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.body.style.overflow = document.body.style.overflow ? null : 'hidden';
```

Comment: That would turn it on and off?

Comment: Yes, if overflow exist it will be remove, else will set 'hidden'

Comment: Yep. Brilliant.

Comment: not brillant, you forget   `x.classList.toggle('change')` return a boolean value, usable to directly set the overflow toggle